# Is it possible to add Swift documentation comments after (i.e. to the side of) a variable?

Tags: swift, xcode, markdown, comments, documentation-generation

For example, instead of this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    /// My first comment
    let myVar1: Int
    /// My second comment
    let myVar2: Int
    /// My third comment
    let myVar3: Int
}
```

Is there a way to write the documentation comment as e.g.:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let myVar1: Int //< My first comment
    let myVar2: Int //< My second comment
    let myVar3: Int //< My third comment
}
```

Comment: The best you can do is to put it on the left: `/** useful comment */ let myVar: Int`.

Comment: What a weird request! Never thought of it. Not important to me, because it doesn't scale to more than one line, but upvoted anyway.